# Error handling VBA where range sheet does not exist

Tags: vba, error-handling

I'm on XL2007 - Windows 7.

I need an element of error handling in the below code.
Some of the values in range rngburndown do not exist as worksheets, and i need the VBA to skip these cells, and copy the rows that do exist as worksheets to the nextavailable row in the matching worksheet name.

```
Sub Retrieve_Forecasts()

Dim objWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim rngBurnDown As RANGE
Dim rngCell As RANGE
Dim strPasteToSheet As String
Dim objNewSheet As Worksheet
Dim rngNextAvailbleRow As RANGE

'DEFINE SOURCE WORKSHEET
Set objWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Forecasts")

'DEFINE LIST OF FORECASTS - INCLUDING VALUES WHICH MAY NOT EXIST AS WORKSHEETS
Set rngBurnDown = objWorksheet.RANGE("A2:A" & objWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

'LOOP THROUGH RANGE
For Each rngCell In rngBurnDown.Cells

    objWorksheet.Select

If rngCell.Value <> "" Then
'SELECT ROW
rngCell.EntireRow.Select

'COPY
Selection.Copy

'FIND AND PASTE WHERE WORKSHEET NAME MATCHES FORECAST LIST

Set objNewSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(rngCell.Value)
objNewSheet.Select

Set rngNextAvailbleRow = objNewSheet.RANGE("A1:A" & objNewSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

RANGE("A" & rngNextAvailbleRow.Rows.Count + 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End If

Next rngCell

objWorksheet.Select
objWorksheet.Cells(1, 1).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Do the lines in question throw an error or just copy empty cells (aka do nothing)?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the commands "On Error GoTo 0" to ignore all errors or use "On Error Resume Next" to ignore the error and execute the next instruction as shown in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hsw66as.aspx

Example:

```
For Each rngCell In rngBurnDown.Cells

On Error GoTo 0    

    objWorksheet.Select

If rngCell.Value <> "" Then
'SELECT ROW
rngCell.EntireRow.Select

'COPY
Selection.Copy

'FIND AND PASTE WHERE WORKSHEET NAME MATCHES FORECAST LIST

Set objNewSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(rngCell.Value)
objNewSheet.Select

Set rngNextAvailbleRow = objNewSheet.RANGE("A1:A" & objNewSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

RANGE("A" & rngNextAvailbleRow.Rows.Count + 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
End If

Next rngCell
```